# Converting Kinect output to HSV error on Python

Tags: python, opencv, kinect

I m working on Kinect and Python, I need to convert the output of Kinect to HSV, but I see the error on executing my python program.

This is my piece of my code:

```
while True:
    depth = getDepthMap()
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(depth, (5, 5), 0)
    image = (blur * 255).round().astype(np.uint8)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  # convert it to hsv
```

Out:

```
cv2.error: /root/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7564: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

[Here is my full code on GitHub](https://github.com/iman67/kinect-object-/blob/master/960412hsv.py)

Comment: not sure what are you trying to achieve with it, but, 1) depth data is one channel and usually 16 bits you are treating it as a normal BGR image, 2) depth data should not be treated as a normal image, unless that you want to specifically do it. Each pixel tells you the depth of it, not a color, if you blur it, then you may be adding or reducing the depth of the pixel, and this could be sometimes by a lot. 3) if you still want to go with it, treat it as a greyscale image

Comment: I read your complete code, and saw that you actually converting it first to uint8. It should be treated as a greyscale without more conversion. This means that you have to convert it gray to HSV, but since opencv don't have that conversion, you will need to convert it to BGR and then to HSV....

Comment: I want to use Kinect to detect the closest object on my robot. tnxxxx a lot

Comment: mabe using something like KMeans may help you identify objects that are more or less in the same range, if you add the color information from the RGB camera you may get even better results. You may try to use something like the blob detector, if you can filter the background. However you should take a look first to depth segmentation tutorials and papers to know how to proceed. It is not such a trivial task

Comment: thank you so much!!! its work and I can detect the closest object with Kinect and mark object